# Microservice arquitecture

Tags: backend, microservices

i have a project in production that was built using monolith arquitecture is an ecommerce and now I like to move to microservices.

I read in many sites about the microservice arquitecture and I understand the pros and cons, but i need understand the real deploy.

So, for example I need create 3 services for handle each business unit, 1 for the user, 2 for the catalog and the last for the orders.. in this Moment I have an API that expose each method for that operations and all operations run in the monolith arquitecture using MVC (I use codeigniter).

Now I understand that in the microservices arquitecture I should be separate  each service with your own database and could be have a serveretc, and I can communicate the services using API request.. but the next not is clear for me..

1. I should be create one subdomain for each microservice? Example:

Htt://apiusers.site.com/create
 
Etc...

2. if use PHP I should be use curl request for communicate the services between them? Is the right way?

Best.

Comment: This is a really broad, opinion-soliciting question, which is off-topic for StackOverflow. And there is no "right" way. A great discussion to have, but unfortunately not here.

Comment: Hi thank you but where I can found information related this?

Comment: Many blogs and other articles have been written about this. Lots of information can be found, even with a simple web search for `"microservice architecture"`.